# Using a function locally to checks blank strings

Tags: bash, function, local

Cannot understand why the function `myfunc` fails. I put a string in `src` and `dst`, and I get the message

```
src is blank
dst is blank
```

Here is the code

```
zblank ()
{

 local  s="$1"

 declare -i f=1 num=0
 [[ $s =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && num=1
 return $num
 
}

myfunc
{
  src="angio"
  dst="angio"
  (
    function myzblank() { zblank "$@"; }

    myzblank "$src" && printf '%s\n' "src is blank"
    myzblank "$dst" && printf '%s\n' "dst is blank"
  )
}
```

Comment: `bash -x` is your friend. (Which is to say: Enable logging).

Comment: That said, this code works _exactly_ how it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `return $num`, the result is interpreted as an exit status.

Exit status 0 means success.
Every nonzero exit status means failure.

Thus, when you set `num=1` only if `[[ $s =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]`, you're reporting success unless that happens, so the `&&` branch is executed.

---

If you want `zblank` to return success only if the variable you pass it is blank, it should instead look like:

```
zblank() { [[ $1 =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]; }
```

- You don't need `return`: By default the return value of a function is that of the last command it ran.
- You don't need `$s`: it doesn't make things any terser or clearer than `$1`.
- You don't need `declare -i`: When a variable is used in an arithmetic context its value is treated as numeric even if it was a string previously.

And if you wanted it to return success only in the case where `$1` is *not* all-spaces, you could write it as:

```
znonblank() { ! [[ $1 =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]; }
```

...addition of a leading `!` being the only change needed.

---

All that said -- you don't need bash extensions like `[[ ]]` to do this at all. POSIX sh is powerful enough for what you're doing here:

```
zblank() {
  case $1 in
    *[![:space:]]*) return 1;; # At least one non-space character exists
    *)              return 0;; # No non-spaces exist; success.
  esac
}
```

Comment: Thank you Charles for understanding what is happening.  Got to the same conclusion as well.  Did not keep in mind that 0 is considered success.  Instead my mindset was about 1 being true and 0 being false.  A strategy I regularly use to remind me if an option is to be applied or not.